# jQuery: function not excecuted twice when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and the function "placeNewSponsor" should repeat itself every 4 seconds. (the function should places images, hides them after 3 secondes, waits 1 seconds and repeat itself). But when I test this, the the function only executes once.

```js
function placeNewSponsor() {
  $('.sponsorContainer').each(function() {

    var imageCount = $(".imageContainer").children().length;

    do {
      randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageCount + 1);
    } while ($.inArray(randomInt, usedNumbers) !== -1);

    usedNumbers.push(randomInt);
    var randomImage = $('.imageContainer a:nth-child(' + randomInt + ')').clone();

    $(this).append(randomImage);
  });

  usedNumbers = [];

  // Hide after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sponsorContainer').hide();
  }, 3000);

  // Re-activate function
  setTimeout(placeNewSponsor, 4000);
}

placeNewSponsor();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hide the container, but you never reshow them.

```
$('.sponsorContainer').show();  //show them
setTimeout(function(){ $('.sponsorContainer').hide(); }, 3000);  //hides them
```